# How SML achieve abstraction?

Tags: sml

I am new in SML and it is my first time to learn a functional language. I suppose there is abstraction of SML. I have not found perfect explanation of how to achieve abstraction in SML. Does anyone can offer a explanation?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what mean by "abstraction"?

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, there are at least two forms of "abstraction" in programming:

- Abstracting the client (parameterisation)
- Abstracting the implementation (encapsulation)

(If you care, these correspond to universal and existential quantification in logic and type theory.)

In ML, parameterisation can be done on two levels. Either in the small, using *functions* (abstraction over values) and *polymorphism* (abstraction over types). Note in particular that functions are first-class, so you can parameterise one function over another. For example:

```
fun map f []      = []
  | map f (x::xs) = f x :: map f xs
```

abstracts list transformation over the transforming function `f` as well as the element types.

In the large, parameterisation can be done using the module system: a *functor* abstracts a whole module over another module (i.e., over both values and types). For example, you could also write the map function as a functor:

```
functor Mapper(type t; type u; val f : t -> u) =
struct
  fun map []      = []
    | map (x::xs) = f x :: map xs
end
```

But usually you use functors for mass abstraction, i.e., in cases where there is more than just a single function you need to parameterise.

Encapsulation is also achieved by using modules. Specifically, by *sealing* them, i.e., hiding details of their types behind a signature. For example, here is a (naive) implementation of integer sets:

```
signature INT_SET =
sig
  type set
  val empty : set
  val add : int * set -> set
  val mem : int * set -> bool
end

structure IntSet :> INT_SET =  (* ':>' hides the implementation of type set *)
struct
  type set = int list
  val empty = []
  fun add(x, s) = x::s
  fun mem(x, s) = List.exists (fn y => y = x) s
end
```

Outside the structure `IntSet`, its type `set` is fully *abstract*, i.e., it cannot be interchanged with lists. That is the purpose of the so-called *sealing* operator `:>` for modules.

Both forms of abstraction can occur together. For example, in ML one would usually implement a set as a functor:

```
signature ORD =
sig
  type t
  val compare : t * t -> order
end

signature SET =
sig
  type elem
  type set
  val empty : set
  val add : elem * set -> set
  val mem : elem * set -> bool
end

functor Set(Elem : ORD) :> SET where type elem = Elem.t =
struct
  type elem = Elem.t
  datatype set = Empty | Branch of set * elem * set

  val empty = Empty

  fun add(x, Empty) = Branch(Empty, x, Empty)
    | add(x, Branch(l, y, r)) =
      case Elem.compare(x, y) of
        LESS => Branch(add(x, l), y, r)
      | EQUAL => Branch(l, y, r)
      | GREATER => Branch(l, y, add(x, r))

  fun mem(x, Empty) = false
    | mem(x, Branch(l, y, r)) =
      case Elem.compare(x, y) of
        LESS => mem(x, l)
      | EQUAL => true
      | GREATER => mem(x, r)
end
```

This implementation of sets works for any type for which an ordering function can be provided. Unlike the naive implementation before, it also uses a more efficient search tree as its implementation. However, that is not observable outside, because the type's implementation is again hidden.

Answer (score 1):

SML programs frequently are build on a descriptive types for the problem at hand. The language then uses pattern matching to figure out what case your are working with.

```
datatype Shape = Circle of real | Rectangle of real*real | Square of real

val a = Circle(0.2)
val b = Square(1.3)
val c = Rectangle(4.0,2.0)

fun area (Circle(r)) = 3.14 * r * r
  | area (Square(s)) = s * s
  | area (Rectangle(b,h)) = b * h
```

Does this help to explain a little about sml?

Answer (score 0):

In SML you can define "abstractions" by means of using a combination of things like algebraic data types and signatures.

Algebraic data types let you define new types specific to the problem domain and signatures let you provide functionality/behavior around those types and provide a convenient way to implement information hiding and extensibility and reusability.

Combining this things you can create "abstractions" whose implementation details are hidden from you and that you simply understand through their public interfaces (whatever the signature expose).